# Pass value from partial to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a page that has an area for partial views, like this:

[image]

The partial view changes depending on which section the user is in, through a tab menu. For each tab chosen, the partial view changes. Every partial view shown there has fields to edit. The buttons `Save` and `Cancel` are always the same, contained in the surrounding view.

When the user presses `Save`, I want to catch the inserted values, which I did in other views through:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="phoneNumber">
```

**C#**

```
string phoneNumber = Request["phoneNumber"].ToString();
```

But here, I keep getting a null exception when the debugger hits the above C# line.

How can I pass a value from a partial view to the controller, contained in an `input`?

**EDIT**

Here's my code: the input in the view (the button)

```
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SaveChanges", "Config")'"/>
```

And the `SaveChanges` method, in the controller:

```
 public ActionResult SaveChanges()
        {
            string phoneNumber = Request["phoneNumber"].ToString();
            ...
```

**Also**, I've tried this for my login form and it works fine:

```
<form method="get" action="../Main/Index">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="30"></p>
    <p>
        <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="25"></p>

    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
    </form>
```

And the controller (MainController)

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            getCredentials();
...

 public void getCredentials()
        {

            if (Request["username"] != null && Request["password"] != null)
...
return View();
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  What controller action does the form post to?  Is the `input` value included in that post?  (Also, why are you using `Request[]` instead of action method parameters?  That's tightly-coupling your code to an active HTTP instance.)  The value doesn't "go from the partial view to the controller."  It goes from the rendered HTML form to the controller by way of an HTTP request.  The view which originally rendered that client-side markup isn't relevant anymore at that point.

Comment: Why are you not using model binding?

Comment: I don't know but since I managed to pass values from views to controller through `Request`, I'm going with that same approach. I'm new to this, just learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually posting any values in your submit.  Look at what this code is doing:

```
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SaveChanges", "Config")'"
```

When you click the button, you just tell the browser to go to the URL for the `SaveChanges` action.  This is invoking a `GET` request and abandoning any form data that was entered client-side.

You should be posting a form instead.  Generally this would involve wrapping the elements and the submit button in a `form` tag (the `@Html.BeginForm` helper method can help with that) so that client-side it looks like:

```
<form method="POST" action="/some/url">
    <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" />
    <!-- other HTML elements -->
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Don't override the action of the submit button unless you still submit the values in some way.  Otherwise you just abandon/ignore those form values.

If your page is one large form, wrap the tabs in a single `form` element.  This can be done by wrapping all of the partials:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveChanges", "Config"))
{
    // put your partials here

    // put your buttons here
}
```

If you want each partial view to be its own individual form then put the `Html.BeginForm` invocation just in that partial view.  This can get a little tricky with the single global submit button, however.  Generally in a setup with multiple forms each one would have its own button.  You can do some JavaScript trickery to show/hide different submit buttons as the tabs change, depending on what you're using to manage your tabs.

Comment: Look at my edit: I already did this for my login form and it works fine. You say I'm not actually posting but it works elsewhere so it should work here too. I'm just using what I achieved before, trying to adapt it to this new situation

Comment: @chiapa: Your login form works because it doesn't override the form post with a custom `onclick` handler.  It's a normal form, so it works normally as one would expect.  You're not using what you used before, you're doing something entirely different.

Comment: yes, it's not the same, you are right. But removing the `onclick` handler didn't help

Comment: @chiapa: It's probably not as simple as that, depending on how you've structured it.  Is the submit button inside the `form` element?  If not then it won't submit the form when you click it.  (Notice in your login form the submit button is inside the `form` element.)  Forgetting any server-side concepts of controllers and views, the rendered HTML in the browser needs to have a valid `form` and needs to post that form to a URL.  Is your HTML `form` valid?  Does it contain the `input` elements you need it to?  Does it contain the submit button?  Does it have a valid URL as an `action` attribute?

Comment: OK, I just did that: placing the buttons inside the form and now the values are passed. Thanks for your time @David! Anyway, from the feedback I got with this question I know this is not the best way to do it (model binding? creating models?)...

Comment: @chiapa: Model binding is a step in the right direction, yes.  Essentially the ASP.NET MVC engine will automatically populate action method parameters with values from the request.  So if your action method has a `string phoneNumber` in its parameter list then that would have the `phoneNumber` value passed from the form.  From there it can get much more powerful (and more complicated) by creating custom models for your data, that way you can have a single parameter of a custom type rather than a ton of strings for example.  Just keep going with the tutorials, you'll work it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can Create a View model for each partial, and then a View Model that contains all of them, in that case you would receive the the information of all tabs when you submit the form that receive the Parent View Model.
something like :

```
public class ParentViewModel{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Option1ViewModel Option1 { get; set; }
    public Option2ViewModel Option2 { get; set; }
    public Option3ViewModel Option3 { get; set; }
    public Option4ViewModel Option4 { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess this is the direction to go but I'm still learning and this concept seems a bit too complex for now. 1+